# Autocomplete Directive in ng-repeat loop Angular

Tags: jquery, angularjs, autocomplete, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I just have a question for the Angular heads.
I am fighting on a problem with an autocomplete custom directive.
My autocompletes events are loaded in a `directive` etc.

For some reasons I have to put an autocomplete input field in each line of a `<table>` element.

For that, I use the `ng-repeat` attribute.
But none of the autocomplete fields are working.

When I remove the `ng-repeat` attribute, autocompletes are working...

So my question is, is there a known bug with this?

Thank you

Comment: pls add your code or even better e JSfiddle or sth similar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to **transclude** your directive.

Because your directive is nested in a `ng-repeat` the contents of the directive are not being compiled into the DOM, hence they are not working.

Directives have a `transclude` attribute and coupled with the `ng-transclude` tag will allow your directives to work when nested in a `ng-repeat`

**Some Resources to get you started:**

[This article](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/angularjs-directives-and-the-computer-science-of-javascript.html) is a great starter for directives and has a nice introduction to transclusion.

[Here is another source](http://liamkaufman.com/blog/2013/05/13/understanding-angularjs-directives-part1-ng-repeat-and-compile/) giving some examples of an *transclude* and *compile* in a ng-repeat.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am checking it actually. I will tell you more :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer once again it seems to be solving my problem. Didn't know the concept of Tranclusion. Thank you

Comment: @JulienRodrigues Can you show your autocomplete directive?

Answer (score 2):

This great article give a very complete description on how to build and autocomplete: http://hueypetersen.com/posts/2013/06/24/typeahead-with-angular/